# LDAP auth in presto

Tags: presto

I was trying to setup LDAP auth in Presto and was able to configure "user-based" authentication but have some issue with configuring "group-based" auth.

I'm always receiving message that my user is not in LDAP group while `ldapsearch` utility shows that I'm in. 
I did not found any parameter/option in config.properties to use to pass user/password for LDAP search (I suppose that functionality used to find in user is in AD group) while in our infrastructure anonymous searches are restricted. So it might be the case.

It would be nice if someone will tell me:

- are there any parameter (maybe undocumented) to provide user/password
  to query ldap?
- any workaround to implement "group-based" search?

thanks

Comment: can you please help how you have configured presto to do user based authentication on LDAP. i am doing also same but ending up with authentication error